# change master page for list view

Tags: list-view, master-page

I want to set up a separate version of the list view page that uses the minimal page master, so the user can't get to the page edit functionality at the top of the screen, or see the navigation on the left. Indeed, I might even want to use a completely blank master page.

I don't see a way to simply change the master page of a view I create in the browser. I tried changing it in designer, but it only asked me where to connect all the sections I don't want.

From what I've read, I don't see a way of adding the list view web part to a page I add to the site, as they get created at the root of the site, and not at the list level, to the list view web part isn't available.

Not sure which of those two routes is the better one, or if there's some other way that I don't know. I may be mistaken about the list view web part being available to me at all for a page of my own design. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to apply this new "masterpage" for all the Lists in your Site Collection / Site, or just some specific ones?

Comment: what is the use case in that?

Comment: The plan is to use it for all lists, but as I say, it does NOT have to be applied to each VIEW for each list.  We have users who should not only not have access to that functionality, we don't even want them to SEE it, for fear that they'll try to fiddle with it, and call up asking why it's not working. The plan is to guide them to this "no frills" page so they can search the list, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be to hide DOM elements after the page is displayed with some JavaScript

Set a JSLink to your scriptfile in the Misc section of the ListView Properties panel

Note that you can add multiple JSLink URLs to scriptfiles (separate by ; )
So you can load jquery first with JSLink and then you own scriptfile using jQuery code

In SharePoint Online you can even point to any HTTPS url, so your scripts don't have to be inside SharePoint